# Why is this move assignement operator implicitly deleted for unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, move, unique-ptr, noexcept

I have a type `pod` that I'd like to pass a handle around using a `unique_ptr` with custom deleter. Only it doesn't work because the move assignement operator is implicitly deleted. I don't understand exactly why? The deleter is a pod type which typically are nothrow move assignable, so it would meet the requirement specified on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D) no?

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAGykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCBmZqQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BASlpGQKh4VEssfGJtpj2jgJCBEzEBNk%2BfoF2mA6Z9Y0ExZExcQlJCg1NLbntY31hA2VDiQCUtqhexMjsHOYAzGHI3lgA1CbbbmwsJACeAPrEmAqr65gn2McaAII7eweYx6fnVxeb0%2BZl2DH2XiOJw8yVqzFoLxMHy%2B4J%2Bfzco2IYWA1wAbnhMAB3RHI0HfSG/aG4zpEYgkkFgiFQ07IUb4VD04FedJGQ5iWioUS064EP4AEUObJAIGSLHiMs8lwuxGSCDwyGu/MFTFp0KlIGilwIz222BOVmRH0xXgch1S6CRnwA7Bb3od3YcwqKmObHR7DtFUJ4A77kU6xaHPpb3saWMkDMb0QRLslGKxfgAVenW21aoUka5YejGx0mF1%2Bj1MLxEQ6oVPEHUkCCLCAZgBUdsWhwAtEDcag8OhjuWPv7/XnG8RrgA6IuYY3XVDRbQ0iDJRaR/1liOjyu0AX5qfe/fa4WR7fnj7c7F2jDXBCGdD0EXiyUEdDSrwMPAARy8mGuWE6VOe1SD5E9D0Lap5xNNx7URU1Lyjd4c1FFgFBxVYCEDL90GuNgGjCfgRVLEc3Q9e170fZ80IwqiGCfADz3DJCvUOFgmDCZtSNdf1KIfBiaLtAhgNdCt3X1akHBIaF0Mw6scIY/D504hhiIIPtOiQ8dqw5Mx/HYlTXyk6dMDjAwNmuaImGQABrbjtl4j0CKYac5PoxjrlffULmpNcRI3RzSLFDhlloTgAFZeD8DgtFIVBODcaxrElR4NmOUEeFIAhNFC5ZbJACKNH0ThJGi3L4s4XgFBAYqcti0LSDgWAYEQFBUDjOg4nISg0E6%2Bh4mALhKiwfENgANQJQkAHlUxirKaFoY1iBqiBogq6IwkaS5OCyzbmGIS5puXGldt4Pq2EEaaGFoHaGtILAOKMcR7vwO4umpGr7swVROmrTY4q9aoKtoPBogbQ6PCwCqRLwFgzuWKgDGABRJqJWbGDOmRBBEMR2CkbH5CUNQKt0Lh9EMYxkssfQwZqyBljrOEvu7NkTjFUxLGsMwNB7AB1flqugrpnAgVwJj8cmQlmUpyj0VJ0jhCX5YKOF%2BlloZyY6EWGB6cZPFaPRtbhPWZhKQZ4i16Zlat3p1YtiRlgeNYNkdkqOCi0gYrihKOEOVQAA5/G7fxJEOYBkGQQ5hunMxDggXBCBIDLti4RZeHqrRFnywrivCjgytIeGiq9irfeq2rsty5ZmrarDkmrHqID65IuuICJ004QPg9D8PI%2BjsxY94TB8FpQc9H4HHRHEAnJ6JlR1HusnSEJBtkgR93Pe93hfem6sG9FVAqH9oOQ7DiOo5juOIA8fq4hTtOM%2Br5YEEwJgsHiZt3cL4viu3yqOAVzqs/UgBUS7522OVe65cq4NWzu7MwUCfZVVgVnZY1IVqZBAJIIAA%3D)

```
#include <memory_resource> 
#include <memory> 
#include <optional>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
 
using allocator_t = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte>;

struct pod
{
    int a;
    bool b;
};


template <typename T>
struct allocator_delete
{
    auto operator()(T* p) -> void {
        allocator_.delete_object(p);
    }
    allocator_t allocator_;
};

using pod_handle_t = std::unique_ptr<pod, allocator_delete<pod>>;


struct msg_outbound_metainfo_t
{
    pod_handle_t msg_handle_;
};

int main()
{
    pod_handle_t ptr;

    std::vector<msg_outbound_metainfo_t> vec;

    auto& meta = vec.emplace_back();
    meta.msg_handle_ = std::move(ptr);
}
```

**Error**

```
<source>:41:37: error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&&) [with _Tp = pod; _Dp = allocator_delete<pod>]'
   41 |     meta.msg_handle_ = std::move(ptr);
      |                                     ^
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/memory:76,
                 from <source>:2:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:406:19: note: 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&&) [with _Tp = pod; _Dp = allocator_delete<pod>]' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
  406 |       unique_ptr& operator=(unique_ptr&&) = default;
      |                   ^~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:406:19: error: use of deleted function 'std::__uniq_ptr_data<_Tp, _Dp, true, false>& std::__uniq_ptr_data<_Tp, _Dp, true, false>::operator=(std::__uniq_ptr_data<_Tp, _Dp, true, false>&&) [with _Tp = pod; _Dp = allocator_delete<pod>]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:243:24: note: declared here
  243 |       __uniq_ptr_data& operator=(__uniq_ptr_data&&) = delete;
      |                        ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: I don't see any move constructors here. Where do you see move constructors? All I see is a move assignment operator complaining about something.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  Indeed fixed for the title

Comment: Well, polymorphic_allocator deletes assignment https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/polymorphic_allocator

Comment: fwiw `msg_outbound_metainfo_t` and `std::vector` are not related to the question.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Which is basically saying that an allocator can only be constructed into an object and not later reassigned... I understand. Can I work around this somehow?

Comment: I suppose you could hand write assignment for `allocator_delete`. And then assert the allocators are the same.